# How to mock s3 put object request using mockK?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, amazon-s3, junit5, mockk

I have a function below which uploads data to s3

```
val s3Client = S3Client.create()
    
data class S3Object(
     val bucket: String,
     val key: String,
     val contents: String,
     val contentType: String
)
        
 fun putS3Object(s3Object: S3Object){
     val putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket(s3Object.bucket)
                        .key(s3Object.key.toString())
                        .contentType(s3Object.contentType)
                        .build()
     s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromString(s3Object.contents))
  }
```

I am mocking it as below:

```
every { S3Client.create()} returns s3Client

val s3Object = S3Object("test-bucket", "/test/key", "test-event", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
val putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(s3Object.bucket)
            .contentType(s3Object.contentType)
            .key(s3Object.key)
            .build()
val putObjectResponse = PutObjectResponse
            .builder()
            .build()
every{ s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromString(s3Object.contents))} answers {putObjectResponse}
```

I am creating the s3 PutObjectRequest and PutObjectResponse as part of the mock. However when I try to run my test I get the following mockK exception:

io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: S3Client(#4).putObject(PutObjectRequest(Bucket=test-bucket, ContentType=application/json; charset=UTF-8, Key="/test/key"), software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody@49322d04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, is the call to `s3Client.putObject(..)` what you are trying to test.. that the data that gets sent to that method is correct?  I will assume so.

It'll be easier if you separate the Class under test versus the test class.  So in the main code line you should have something like this:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest

data class S3Object(
    val bucket: String,
    val key: String,
    val contents: String,
    val contentType: String,
)

class S3Service(
    // always in inject your dependencies then we can override then you override them in a test
    private val s3Client: S3Client = S3Client.create() 
) {
    fun putS3Object(s3Object: S3Object) {
        val putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(s3Object.bucket)
            .key(s3Object.key.toString())
            .contentType(s3Object.contentType)
            .build()
        s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromString(s3Object.contents))
    }
}
```

And now the test class:

```
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.mockk.clearAllMocks
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.slot
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse

class S3ServiceTest {

    // you need a mock the client since this is what you want to mock to check the invocation
    private val s3Client = mockk<S3Client>()
    private lateinit var s3Service: S3Service

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() {
        // its supposedly marginally more efficient to define your mocks once and clear then not instantiate each time
        clearAllMocks()
        // inject the mock s3Client so you do not get the `S3Client.create()` one
        s3Service = S3Service(s3Client)
    }

    @Test
    fun `putObject call correctly formed`() {
        val s3Object = S3Object(
            "test-bucket",
            "/test/key",
            "test-event",
            "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        )
        every { s3Client.putObject(any<PutObjectRequest>(), any<RequestBody>()) } returns mockk()
        s3Service.putS3Object(s3Object)
    }
```

Now this is incomplete - it doesn't assert anything.  But the point here is that in the line `every { s3Client.putObject(any<PutObjectRequest>(),...` I am setting up that Mockk will capture ANY input to the `putObject()`.  It it wrong to instruct Mockk to expect a particular input in this case... rather you want to see what that in put is and then test it (see later).

I needed to use `<PutObjectRequest>` because there are several `s3Client.putObject()` so mockk needs to know which you are listening to.

And another change was the end of the line. You put this:

```
} answers {putObjectResponse}
```

this is ok, but two things

1. for the test do you really care what the `putObject()` returns?  You might do if this is part of a more complex test.  Use `returns mock()` if you don't care
2. There are two "endings" you can use here... `returns OBJECT` or `answers { LAMBDA }`.  The second case is useful when you don't know what to return under after later, in this case you output is static is it is more efficient to use `returns OBJECT`...

In the case of of needing a proper return do this:

```
        val putObjectResponse = PutObjectResponse
            .builder()
            .build()
        every { s3Client.putObject(any<PutObjectRequest>(), any<RequestBody>()) } returns putObjectResponse
```

Now how can we actually see if the call to `putObject` was correctly made? For this you need a different feature called a `slot` which you use like this:

```
    @Test
    fun `putObject call correctly formed2`() {
        val s3Object = S3Object(
            "test-bucket",
            "/test/key",
            "test-event",
            "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        )
        every { s3Client.putObject(any<PutObjectRequest>(), any<RequestBody>()) } returns mockk()

        val pubObjectRequestSlot = slot<PutObjectRequest>()
        every { s3Client.putObject(capture(pubObjectRequestSlot), any<RequestBody>()) } returns mockk()

        s3Service.putS3Object(s3Object)

        pubObjectRequestSlot.captured.bucket() shouldBe "test-bucket"
        pubObjectRequestSlot.captured.key() shouldBe "/test/key"
        // more assertions here...
        // and of course you can capture the RequestBody argument too
    }
```